# Ubuntu Ethernet Connection cable unplugged

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, 22.04, ethernet

I have tried setting up my ethernet for a few weeks now without any progress. My wifi is working, but its too slow. I have already tried multiple cables and different routes. Would appreciate any help at this point.

I also for some reason have two ethernet interfaces, even though I only have one ethernet port on my laptop.

[image: network manager screenshot]

Here are my stats:

```
OS Name: Ubunu 22.04.1 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
Hardware Model: Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 2a
```

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:5a:fc:0e:03:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.4/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 1994sec preferred_lft 1994sec
    inet6 2a02:2454:3a5:5c00:c1e9:10ae:62e8:89e2/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 171855sec preferred_lft 84315sec
    inet6 2a02:2454:3a5:5c00:bbf7:4b05:bcdd:fbd5/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 171855sec preferred_lft 85455sec
    inet6 fe80::4558:ccc2:29cd:a5a6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: enp2s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:f3:ab:f4:2e:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:f3:ab:f4:2e:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**sudo lspci -v**

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34, IOMMU group 12
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at fd804000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fd800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 4852
    Physical Slot: 0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 92, IOMMU group 13
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at fd700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-88-52-01
    Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_pci
    Kernel modules: rtw89_pci, wl

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67, IOMMU group 15
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at fd504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fd500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168
```

**sudo nano /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**uname -r**

```
5.15.0-52-generic
```

**dkms status**

```
bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**sudo nmcli**

```
wlp3s0: connected to Lea
        "Realtek Renoir/Cezanne GPP Bridge"
        wifi (rtw89_pci), 14:5A:FC:0E:03:BB, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default, ip6 default
        inet4 192.168.0.4/24
        route4 192.168.0.0/24 metric 600
        route4 default via 192.168.0.1 metric 600
        route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
        inet6 2a02:2454:3a5:5c00:c1e9:10ae:62e8:89e2/64
        inet6 2a02:2454:3a5:5c00:bbf7:4b05:bcdd:fbd5/64
        inet6 fe80::4558:ccc2:29cd:a5a6/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024
        route6 2a02:2454:3a5:5c00::/64 via fe80::6a02:b8ff:fe94:4426 metric 600
        route6 default via fe80::6a02:b8ff:fe94:4426 metric 600

enp2s0f0: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8168), 38:F3:AB:F4:2E:FB, hw, mtu 1500

enp5s0: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8168), 38:F3:AB:F4:2E:FA, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 62.117.5.126 217.68.162.126
        domains: box
        interface: wlp3s0

        servers: 2a02:2457:20c:101::126 2a02:2457:10c:101::126
        interface: wlp3s0
```

Comment: I can not find anything in the info you have here that matches with the title cable unplugged.

Comment: @David I added a screenshot of the network manager.